# How to link a user from a firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a posting website with **vue and firebase**, when a user creates a post, their username will be displayed on the post.

For example:

Created by `user1`

This all works fine.
Now I am working on a user page, where you can see the name and email of the user.

The problem there is that I don't get the email and name displayed.

This is my code:

piece of PostDetails page

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'UserDetails', params: { userId: playlist.userId } }" class="username">
    Created by {{ playlist.userName }}
</router-link>
```

UserDetails page:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ user.displayName }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import getDocument from "@/composables/getDocument";

export default {
  props: ["userId"],
  setup(props) {
      
    const { error, document } = getDocument("users", props.userId);
    const userName = document.value.displayName
    return {
      error,
      userName,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

This is the website itself:
[Website](https://xamples-5d4a6.web.app/)

And this is what the database looks like:

1. posts
   [image: posts]
2. users
   [image: users]

#### Summary

---

What I want to do, is whenever you are on a post, you can click on the username (this I have already done) and then on the userDetails page, you can see the user and email from the post that you were on.

Comment: Do not save anywhere users password !!! Just let authentication consume it.

Comment: Same with email addresses you should not share that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One classical approach in the NoSQL world is to **denormalize** the data in such a way you get the necessary data for a specific application screen with only one query. In other words, you don't "link" the two records, using a join like you would do in the SQL world, but you put all the data in the record to be displayed.

More concretely it means that in each Playlist doc you would duplicate the data of its author (`userName`, as you already do, but also `email`).

One side effect of this approach is that you need to keep the values in sync (i.e. the one in the User document and the ones in the Playlists documents). This synchronization could be done with a Cloud Function triggered if the User doc is modified.

Again, you should not be afraid to duplicate data and denormalize your data model. Here is a "famous" [post](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) about NoSQL data-modeling approaches:

Comment: But how could duplicating solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your problem. I understand that on a page/screen that shows a Playlist, you want to show the name and email of its author. If this is the correct understanding, then the above approach will do the trick.

Comment: well, actually this is my problem: I have a post page with a username in the post, from the user that created that post. And when you click on that username, I want to direct to a different page with more details from that user, for example their email and username.

Comment: Ok I understand. So you can either denormalize the data as explained in the answer OR you could use the value in the field `userId` to open a new page, pass this ID in the URL (or in a Vuex store) and fetch the user record in this new page (this could be a better option if there is a lot of data to show in this new page). I also see you accepted the answer, so you choose to go with the denormalization :-)